# List permissions for a site using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, microsoft-graph, azure-ad

We use the graph API from Microsoft to get the details about site, drives, files, folder, etc.

The graph API works as expected and returns the results for those queries.

However, If I try to get the permissions using `/sites/{site_id}/permissions` endpoint I get:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('{site_id}')/permissions",
    "value": []
}
```

Comment: Are you trying it with `Sites.FullControl.All` permissions? Check this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I see. I was trying this with the Sites.Selected permission.

Comment: Is it working for you now with `Sites.FullControl.All`?

Comment: I am yet to try this. I currently was having only the Sites.Selected access.
I was trying to have a workaround to check the folder/file level permissions for the SharePoint App-Only (without delegated access). I found that this might not be possible with the current version of the SharePoint and even with the Graph APIs

Comment: Sure, try it and let me know if it works or still facing same issue.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Comment: Yes I checked upon the permissions part and I wasn't having the FullControl access earlier. Post that the permissions started coming in as expected

Answer (score 0):

You are using correct Microsoft Graph endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sitesId}/permissions
```

However, you will need below Graph permissions to list SharePoint site permissions:

[image]

**Documentation**: [List permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)